# R - Split character vector using regex

Tags: r, regex, string, logfile

I've got some kind of logfile I'd like to read and analyse. Unfortunately the files are saved in a pretty "ugly" way (with lots of special characters in between), so I'm not able to read in just the lines with each one being an entry. The only way to separate the different entries is using regular expressions, since the beginning of each entry follows a specified pattern.

My first approach was to identify the pattern in the character vector (I use read_file from the readr-package) and use the corresponding positions to split the vector with strsplit. Unfortunately the positions seem not always to match, since the result doesn't always correspond to the entries (I'd guess that there's a problem with the special characters).

A typical line of the file looks as follows:

> 16/10/2017, 21:51 - George: This is a typical entry here

The corresponding regular expressions looks as follows:

```
([[:digit:]]{2})/([[:digit:]]{2})/([[:digit:]]{4}), ([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2}) - ([[:alpha:]]+):
```

The first thing I want is a data.frame with each line corresponding to a specific entry (in a next step I'd split the pattern into its different parts).

What I tried so far was the following:

```
regex.log = "([[:digit:]]{2})/([[:digit:]]{2})/([[:digit:]]{4}), ([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2}) - ([[:alpha:]]+):"
log.regex = gregexpr(regex.log, file.log)[[1]]
log.splitted = substring(file.log, log.regex, log.regex[2:355]-1)
```

As can be seen this logfile has 355 entries. The first ones are separated correctly. How can I separate the character vector using a regular expression without loosing the information of the regular expression/pattern?

Comment: I think you want to use a combination of `grepl(regex.log, file.log)` to identify matching rows and `gsub(regex.log,"", file.log)` to extract the text.

Answer (score 2):

Use capturing and non-capturing groups to identify the parts you want to keep, and be sure to use anchors:

```
file.log  =  "16/10/2017, 21:51 - George: This is a typical entry here"
regex.log = "^((?:[[:digit:]]{2})\\/(?:[[:digit:]]{2})\\/(?:[[:digit:]]{4}), (?:[[:digit:]]{2}):(?:[[:digit:]]{2}) - (?:[[:alpha:]]+)): (.*)$"

gsub(regex.log,"\\1",file.log)
>> "16/10/2017, 21:51 - George"
gsub(regex.log,"\\2",file.log)
>> "This is a typical entry here"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain what you changed in the regular expression?

Comment: I'd recommend using [regex101.com] to understand the regex.  That hast probably the best explanation (don't forget to convert the double slash `"\\"` to a single `"\"` since the double slash is just for passing the string with a single into R.   In short, I made your groups `(blah blah blah)` into non-capturing groups `(?:blah blah blah)`, and then wrapped the two parts of the expression that I wanted into their own groups so they could be used in the substitution expression (`"\\1"`)

Comment: Thanks. Your code works, but unfortunately it doesn't work with the file I have. I'm currently trying to find out where the problem is.

Comment: There's a little problem with your version of the regular expression. The part at the end matches the rest of the character vector (together with all entries after the first one). Using this I'd have to use a recursion over the whole string (which would be pretty inefficient). edit: Sorry, I think I forgot the mention that the whole logfile is just one extremely long character vector.

Comment: I would strongly consider separating the process of (A) splitting the file into a vector where each element is a record, and (B) Parsing the individual records. This answer only parses (a vector of) individual records.

Comment: Yes, that's my next step (which should be straightforward). Currently I've got the problem that I want to separate the different entries. edit: I've separated the entries, thanks. I'll post an answer here a bit later.